# Achievements locked again after a while Google play games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I had implemented Google Play Games into my app (in beta test). I added some achievements (more than 5) and have done all the related settings like described in the API.  I am testing this with the same google account as my developer account, this is added as a test account inside the console. To unlock an achievement I call

```
  Games.Achievement.unlock(mGoogleApiClient,achievement);
```

It works and my achievements are unlocked. To call the users Play Games Achievements I use the intent like stated in the api:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),1);
```

The user achievements are shown in the Play Games user view, so everything seems to be ok.
The strange thing is, after a while, let´s say half an hour, the achievements are in reveal (locked) state again.

I can´t find any hint in the API and Developer Guides, that the achievements are reset automatically in the beta test phase or in an unreleased state. Is this a normal behaviour and it will work after official release or do I miss something anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was because I used an unsigned APK. For get the tests work correctly, it must be a release signed apk. I also put the same released version into the alpha test.

Comment: Can you explain what did you precisely do to fix this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding the `achievementId` when you call `startActivityForResult`.

So, instead of calling

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),1);
```

use

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

See [Unlocking achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements#unlocking_achievements) for more information.

Comment: thanks but this is not what I meant. The second Parameter is an "arbitrary" integer, which means, take any integer you want. That´s stated out in the link. The second Parameter is only for the method `startActivityForResult()` and has nothing to do with calling the achievements.

Comment: Additional: As I described, I see my unlocked achievements for about half an hour, maybe an hour. After that time, they are gone. It´s like the achievements are reset automatically...