# Achievements aren't updating with google play games

Tags: synchronization, google-play-games, unreal-engine4, leaderboard, achievements

so i have made two games with unreal engine (BLUE PRINT ONLY) for android which are published and has already set achievements and leaderboard in google play.

Problem is when player unlocks achievement, it popups "unlocked achievement" and also it update in play games and google play app shows all achievements which are unlocked but temporary. So what's happening is i can unlock achievements, achievement popip shows, play games update achievements and after some time (about 30 min without playing game or opening game) all achievement locks again automatically. And it is happening in my both games. I already checked my all codes are ok.

M i missing any api or permission ? or it is problem form google ?

Comment: I'm interested to know any suggestion as well, bec soon I will hit this area at my developement.

btw, I'm interesting to know games you created using unreal to try it out on my phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295924/google-play-games-achievements-reset-every-day or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505156/achievements-locked-again-after-a-while-google-play-games

Comment: Here it is my game link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tappyarrow.codeDNA          i checked all credentials and api and i also my apk is signed as droidbomb suggested

Comment: May b i m missing something in apis, can u list down which apis should i use for play games, achievements and leaderboard ? So that i can confirm with my apis. And is it possible that it cannot work because i enabled few extra unneeded apis ? Thanx for reply guys

Comment: Well i did found solution but kind of temporary.  As i was checking all id and finger print i found that my app id in google play debeloper console is different than google api console. So i change id in developer console via linking sender id from firebase and it worked but temporary. After sometime app id changes automatically again and new users can't even login.  What should i do ? I m kind a stuck on this for a week.